# How to convert sound wave to midi in C#?

Tags: c#, wav, midi

Does anyone know how to convert an analog sound wave to a MIDI file?

I know that differs from WAV to MP3, but that's not important for now. I only want to learn the basic logic of the conversion.

Comment: Just imagine you record some music on the radio, give this soundfile to your software and you'll get back all the notes for all instruments used within it. If you know how to solve this problem (which you are actually describing) you can make a lot of money with it!

Comment: @Oliver: There's software that converts MIDI to sheet music - MuseScore at http://musescore.org/  So all Emre has to do is convert an analog sound wave to a MIDI file, and he'll be home free.

Comment: @Gilbert: Yes, MIDI -> Wave = simple; MIDI -> notes = simple; Wave -> MIDI = lot of money if solved.

Comment: http://is.gd/igp4m -- I've seen soooo many questions about converting MIDI to audio I had to write this.  Please take the time to read it if you are considering writing some software system which needs to do that.

Comment: @Nik Reiman, midi-to-wav is a lot easier than wav-to-midi

Comment: @finnw, yes, but doing both at 100% perfection is a pipe dream.

Answer (score 2):

I realize that you want to write your own wave to MIDI converter.

However, I had no idea that several companies have software that performs wave to MIDI conversion.

For the benefit of those interested, here's a list of **[audio to MIDI programs](http://www.music-notation.info/en/compmus/audio2midi.html)**.

I picked the **[WidiSoft](http://widisoft.com/)** web site to check out because it was at the top of the list, and came up high in a Google search.  English is not their first language.  However, you can download and try the software before you buy it.

This isn't a product review, but depending on your conversion needs, you should be able to find something that already exists.

Answer (score 1):

A wave is the actual sound wave of some sound.
A midi can be thought of as notes of music played on predefined instruments (stored on the computer or on the soundcard).

Therefore, the sound generated by midi is a subset of sound that can be stored in a wave file. This means that you can not convert wave to midi (although you can do it the other way round).

If you know certain things about the waves you wish to convert it might be possible. If, for example, you *know* that the wave contains only a paino, it might be possible to convert that into notes and from that to midi.

Answer (score 0):

Use the ideas from Genetic Programming: Evolution of Mona Lisa project, but applied over sounds instead of images.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you should first break the audio into small clips (maybe .25 sec each). Then you could use FFT to get as many of the frequencies and associated amplitudes you require for each clip (maybe 8?). Then you could round the frequencies to the nearest note. Then I think the conversion of that to MIDI is pretty easy, at least at this basic level. So, you need to write C# software that samples the audio clip (done: see NAudio), and then obtain (I don't know where) software that does the FFT on the clip. Conversion of frequency to a note is a table lookup. You can find commercial software that does conversion too: https://www.celemony.com/en/melodyne/new-in-melodyne-5

Comment: That's an idea...I have an audio track of a drum that came  low quality & need this to drive a MIDI so I can use this to preserve the drummer's technique with a MIDI drum track.